# PHP Wordpress Increment Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
<?php if (types_render_field( "slider-imagine-1", array( 'raw' => true) ) !== "") : ?>
<div class="item">
    <img src="<?php echo(types_render_field( 'slider-imagine-1', array( 'raw' => true) )); ?>" alt="">
</div>
<?php else :?>  <?php endif; ?>
```

I want to repeat this code 10 times, and each time it repeats, the number from the variable "slider-imagine-1" increments by 1.

SOLVED:

```
<?php for($i = 1; $i < 11; $i++) {
    // Increment variable by 1
    $name = "slider-imagine-".$i;

    // Extract incremented variable from WordPress
    $variable = (types_render_field($name, array( "raw" => true) ));

    // If variable is not empty, do this
    if ($variable != "") {
      echo '<div class="item">';
      echo '<img src="'.$variable.'"></img>';
      echo '</div>';
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: I tried to work up with this, but I don't know how to make the connection properly <?php for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++) {echo $i + 1;} ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that maybe

```
    <?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
        $name = "slider-imagine-".$i;
        if (types_render_field($name, array( 'raw' => true) ) !== "") : ?>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="<?php echo(types_render_field($name, array( 'raw' => true) )); ?>" alt="">
     ...
```

Comment: Please paste your new full code inside your original post

Answer (score 0):

You Miss to close php tag to rendre the HTML, you need something like that

```
// Php code in the for loop
if($name !='')
    ?>
     <div>HTML <?php echo $name;?> Continue html<\div>
   <?php
    // Php code
    // If you don't to close php tag
   echo ' <div>'. $name .'<\div>';
```

That only an example on how to mix php and html, this will fit to your needs.